# Working with microseconds

Tags: php, time

I'm working with microseconds on PHP and if the difference is very small I'm getting wrong answers.

Why and how fix this?

**Example:**

```
$t1 = '1452502847.8248';
$t2 = '1452502847.8247';
$min = (float)($t1 - $t2);
var_dump($min); //9.9897384643555E-5

$t1 = '1452502847.8248';
$t2 = '1452502847.8246';
$min = (float)($t1 - $t2);
var_dump($min); //0.00020003318786621
```

Comment: Why are you declaring floats as strings?

Comment: 9.9897384643555E-5 meaning is 0.00009897384643555. 0.00020003318786621 is 2.0003318786621E-4. Your result is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP, like many other, can surprise you in terms of precision math. Please take a look at [this article](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/) for further info on the issue.

So, the results you get are correct, but to make them more useful, you have to round your results to the precision you want (4 decimals in this case). Try this:

```
$min = round($t1-$t2,4);
```